# How do I join a list of dates with database table in entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of every week starting date in the year.

```
List<DateTime> yearWeeks = GetAllDaysOfWeekForYear(DateTime.Now.Year, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

I want to list these alongside my db table:

```
db.planner.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == CustomerId && a.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Join(yearWeeks, c => c.WeekStarting, d => d.ToLongDateString(), (c, d) => new
        {
            yearDate = d.ToLongDateString(),
            c.WeekStarting
        }).ToList();
```

This throws the error

> The type arguments for method Queryable.Join cannot be inferred from
>   the usage.

How would I go about joining the two together with linq?

Answer (score 0):

[`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) takes 4 parameters (the first overloaded version):
The first is the sequence to join to (`yearweeks`), the second is the key from the first sequence (`WeekStarting`), the third parameter is the key from the second sequence, and the fourth parameter takes lambda to select matching elements:

> A function to create a result element from two matching elements.

```
DatesDeclared.planner = db.planners.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == 2 && a.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Join(yearweeks, c => c.WeekStarting, d => d.Value, (c, d) => new
    {
        c.WeekStarting,
        d.Value
    }).ToList();
```

It's more readable to use the query syntax than the lambda syntax and more simpler:

```
var data = from p in planners
                   join w in yearweeks on p.WeekStarting equals w.Value
                   select new
                   {
                       p.WeekStarting,
                       w.Value
                   };
```

Without knowing the type you are returning, I can't know what type is `DatesDeclared.planner`, so the code above returning a list of anonymous type

Comment: I updated my question. I am getting a different error on the join

Comment: What's the type of `yearweeks`?

Comment: List<DateTime> yearWeeks

Comment: Please add the model class composing `planner` object